# Understand es6 and jsx in react

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, reactjs, jsx

I am going through the official redux tutorial. 
`http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html`

In the file

`components/Link.js` have the following code

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

const Link = ({ active, children, onClick }) => {
  if (active) {
    return <span>{children}</span>
  }

  return (
    <a href="#"
       onClick={e => {
         e.preventDefault()
         onClick()
       }}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}

Link.propTypes = {
  active: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Link
```

What I am wondering why function link accepting the variable surrounded by curly braces. Secondly, the return statement inside the if block has the `span` jsx tag without the braces but the secondly the return statement outside the if block with the `<a>` tag has a braces. Can anyone explains why?

**EDIT:** After finding out about destructuring assignment from the answers I read the following article about how to use it in a function and it became very clear to me.
https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [stateless function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions), you can define react classes as plain JS functions when they don't have state and life-cycle methods

The curly braces are placed in there to use an amazing es6 feature called [Destructuring](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/).

Basically using es6 that's the same as doing:

```
const Link = (props) => {
   const { active, children, onClick } = props;
   ...
```

And without using ES6 it would be the same as doing:

```
const Link = (props) => {
   const active = props.active;
   const children = props.children;
   const onClick = props.onClick;
   ....
```

About the return you use brackets when your jsx elements have more then 1 line.

Comment: That's not exactly true. When you extract values from an object as function parameter, these values are not constants.

Comment: @AnthonyDugois the point of the question is not if they are consts or lets, you can assign a var to be a let or a const depending on the situation, the intent is to show the way Destructing works not if the values inside will be constants or not.

Comment: @DiogoCunha thanks for the answer. I think this link explains well about how destructuring assignment works with function. 

https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/

Do you think you can add that to your answer.

Comment: @MuhammadRaihanMuhaimin replaced the link to destructuring with that one

Answer (score 1):

The function argument uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract values from an object.

The braces around JSX are here to keep the indentation clean.

You can do this:

```
return <div>
    lol
  </div>
```

But you can't do this:

```
return
  <div>
    lol
  </div>
```

So, to keep the indentation of JSX clean, you have to wrap the markup with braces.